# Excel percentile with condition formula not working. Returning '#NUM!'

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use the percentile.exc function with a condition to ignore 0 values but it's not working! It returns '#NUM!'

I've tried using an array too but that returns the same result. Could it be something to do with the dataset that excel doesn't like?

Tried both of the following:

```
=PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(Y:Y>0,Y:Y),0.025)

{=IF(Y:Y>0,PERCENTILE.EXC(Y:Y,0.025))}
```

Can anybody provide the answer as to why it doesn't work?!!

Thanks!

Data below:

```
104.54%
76.16%
0.00%
135.09%
72.70%
0.00%
106.99%
0.00%
0.00%
117.36%
0.00%
0.00%
30.67%
0.00%
114.84%
0.00%
42.31%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
69.01%
0.00%
106.85%
0.00%
100.17%
0.00%
146.80%
97.98%
0.00%
100.29%
100.50%
146.80%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
100.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
100.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
99.67%
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula

```
=PERCENTILE.INC(IF(Y:Y,Y:Y),0.025)
```

as an array formula

Comment: Thanks for response, still not working unfortunately though. That returns '#VALUE!'

Comment: PERCENTILE.EXC only works if k is between 1/n and 1-1/n, where n is the number of elements in array.
 
PERCENTILE.INC uses a slightly less accurate algorithm, but it works for any value of k between 0 and 1.

Comment: The problem you have is that, when you remove the zeros from your list you only have 20 values left. This means that Percentile.EXC won't work as the value of k would have to be between 0.05 and 0.95. Your value of 0.025 is too low and will give an error. You need to use percentile.inc instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes complete sense now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a normal non-CSE formula, you can use `AGGREGATE(16,..)` (for PERCENTILE.INC) or `AGGREGATE(18,..)` (for PERCENTILE.EXC), with an directive to exclude zero and **also** error values (2nd parameter = `6`). i.e.

```
=AGGREGATE(16, 6, Y1:Y999/(Y1:Y999<>0), 0.025)
```